# Which Drupal 6 theme framework is good for creating a responsive web design?

Tags: theming

Which Drupal 6 theme framework is good for creating a responsive web design? Is it advisable to use Zen starter-kit to develop a responsive theme?

Answer (score 1):

Omega offers good responsive features. 
"Fully Responsive Grid layouts based on 960.gs standards."

I have used this for many 7 projects but not tried 6, if this is a new project you are starting I would recommending starting with 7.

Answer (score 1):

We used [Adaptive Theme](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) for a few D6 websites.